Не переходит по ссылкам на переведенной версии сайта Drupal 7
Необходимо было создать английскую версию сайта, все сделал, главная страница открывается, но при попытке перейти в английской версии по ссылкам, ссылка меняется, но остается так же главная страница, что это такое и как исправить?

Приведите ваш код, и подробно опишите проблему, тогда мы вам поможем.
